# What's this means: Unmarshalling unknown type code 1279544898 at offset 2616?

Tags: android, crash

Some times just crash:

```
07-09 10:44:29.581  19036-19036/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: toolbox.full, PID: 19036
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{toolbox.full/toolbox.full.setting.ASetting}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@2beebd43: Unmarshalling unknown type code 1279544898 at offset 2616
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@2beebd43: Unmarshalling unknown type code 1279544898 at offset 2616
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2222)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2479)
            at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
            at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:804)
            at org.holoeverywhere.preference.Preference.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(Preference.java:145)
            at org.holoeverywhere.preference.PreferenceGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(PreferenceGroup.java:90)
            at org.holoeverywhere.preference.PreferenceGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(PreferenceGroup.java:90)
            at org.holoeverywhere.preference.Preference.restoreHierarchyState(Preference.java:935)
            at org.holoeverywhere.preference.PreferenceActivity.onRestoreInstanceState(PreferenceActivity.java:794)
            at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1027)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2631)
????????????at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
????????????at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
????????????at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
????????????at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
????????????at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
????????????at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
????????????at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
????????????at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
????????????at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
????????????at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

Comment: Looks like a problem in one of your models. please Post the code for the object you are trying to retrieve from savedinstancestate it is probably a mismatch in that file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model that contains a model as a member variable, application will throw this exception.

Use proguard like this can solve this problem.

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}
```

Comment: this does not help me. Are the proguard files recompiled with the build to apply the changes? Because nothing seems to have changed for my case. My models indeed do have other models as member variables. These memeber models aslo implement the parcelable interface so i think there really shouldn't be a problem serializing the object, yet it keeps crashing with this error